# How to extract substring(html) and another substring (which will be used for regex) and place it all in proper format?

Tags: java, regex, jsp

I have a giant string which contains the below code and I need to extract contains in such a way that,if any HTML comes append it and if any substring that contains following **pattern**, create a link out of it  and it in proper format and place and goes on.

Example:

```
<div id="contentPermission"> 
  [[MI44,MI304,MI409,MI45,MI264,MI108,MI46,MI47,MI48,MI49,MI50,MI51,MI52,MI58,MI530]]

</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>[[LP1137]]</p>
```

**Pattern:**  starting "[[" and ends with "]]"
Form above code:

```
[[anything between these brackets]]
```

So the outside should be like this:

```
<div id="contentPermission"> 

  <a href="index?page=content&id=MI44></a>

  <a href="index?page=content&id=MI304></a>

  <a href="index?page=content&id=MI409></a>

 ......

 ......
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><a href="index?page=content&id=LP1137></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("<div id=\"contentPermission\">"
            + "  [[MI44,MI304,MI409,MI45,MI264,MI108,MI46,MI47,MI48,MI49,MI50,MI51,MI52,MI58,MI530]]"
            + "</div><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>[[LP1137]]</p>");

    System.out.println("Before " + str.toString()+"\n\n\n");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[{2}.[^\\]]*\\]{2}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while(matcher.find()){

        String codes = matcher.group(0);
        codes = codes.substring(2, codes.length()-2);

        StringBuilder urls = new StringBuilder();
        for(String code:codes.split(",")){
            urls.append("<a href=\"index?page=content&id=" + code + "></a>\n");
        }
        str = new StringBuilder(matcher.replaceFirst(urls.toString()));
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    }

    System.out.println("Replaced " + str.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajiv.. it worked. But I could not understand your regex pattern. Could you please elaborate it and explain it to me. Thanks again

Comment: this regex consists of 3 parts

1.  \[{2}   -> search the character "[" and number in {} signifies 2 occurrences of the character "[" 

2.  .[^\]]  -> take all characters starting from "[[" till you find the character "]' **P.S. this is required as the result without this was coming as follows

[[MI44,MI304,MI. . . .MI48,MI49,MI50,MI51,MI52,MI58,MI530]]</div><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><div>&nbsp;</div<p>&nbsp;</p><p>[[LP1137]]

whereas we only want 

[[MI44,MI30. . . .48,MI49,MI50,MI51,MI52,MI58,MI530]]** _Try for yourself_

3.  *\]{2}  ->get the characters till "]]"

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with regex only (no split/loop nor substring) :

```
String content = "<div id=\"contentPermission\">[[MI44,MI304,MI409,MI45,MI264,MI108,MI46,MI47,MI48,MI49,MI50,MI51,MI52,MI58,MI530]]</div><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>[[LP1137]]</p>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[\\[).*?(?=\\]\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

while(m.find())
  content = content.replaceFirst("(\\[\\[).*?(\\]\\])", m.group().replaceAll("(\\w+)(,\\s*\\d*)*", "<a href=\"index?page=content&id=$1\"></a>"));
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for ur solution..!!

Comment: **FYI while is a loop**. your code looks clean but if you look at working of my answer and the internal computations performed by the methods used by you, they are of similar complexity